# File upload php with file array

Tags: php

i try to upload files into my server also to my database.

However, i cannot upload them.

I can see my two files with below code,

```
echo $_FILES['file']['name'][0];
echo $_FILES['file']['name'][1];


$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'][0];
$add = "img01.imgsinemalar.com/images/haber_anasayfa/" . $fileName;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[file_up][tmp_name], $add)) {
    NCore::db('NEWS')->insertAsArray(array('CONTENT' => $_POST['TvSpotdesc'], 'ADD_DATE' => $date, 'TITLE' => $_POST['newsTitle'],IMAGE_MAIN => $add))->execute();
    echo "Haber başarıyla gönderildi.";
} else {
    echo "Failed to upload file Contact Site admin to fix the problem";
}else {
    echo $msg;
}
```

But above code does not upload my files, it goes directly to the else statement, why?

> Failed to upload file Contact Site admin to fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be outputting two notices and a warning from this line:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[file_up][tmp_name], $add)) {
```

The two notices would be because you have not quoted `file_up` and `tmp_name` and the warning to inform you of the reason `move_uploaded_file` has failed, [as documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). You should check out the logs to see these for yourself (development without seeing any error messages is not fun).

The *reason* it fails is that you cannot move a file to a remote server -- `$add` is not a local path.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `$_FILES[file_up][tmp_name]` to `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

There is no such variable as `file_up` as per the code you pasted. Also, files can only be stored on the same server. so gove relative path like `/home/www/myapp/images/` instead of server name.